# Concatenating SELECT into one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I really did pore over all of the various things posted on this, but I can't get any of them to work, possibly because the table I'm using has no kind of identity column (stupid, stupid, stupid!).

I have a list of all people who are contacts associated with a lease in a column called `file_as_name`. The table is called `lease_contacts` unsurprisingly.

In another table, I have a large character column into which I need to stuff the concatenated results, when the table is is grouped by "name, unit, lease_start_date".

In other words, for a group at a property named "Cedar Villas" and "Unit 001" and Lease_start_date = "01/01/2019", I have these values:

```
John Doe
Jane Smith
Allen Smithee
```

In the column, I want to place:

```
John Doe, Jane Smith, Allen Smithee
```

Is this possible?  I think it is, but the grouping by three columns is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) link that @shawnt00 mentioned in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193786/concatenating-results-from-a-column-from-a-select), you could do this with the STUFF/XML method, e.g.:

```sql
declare @lease_contacts table (
    [name] nvarchar(50),
    unit nvarchar(50),
    lease_start_date date,
    file_as_name nvarchar(50)
);

insert @lease_contacts values
    (N'Cedar Villas', N'Unit 001', '2019-01-01', N'John Doe'),
    (N'Cedar Villas', N'Unit 001', '2019-01-01', N'Jane Smith'),
    (N'Cedar Villas', N'Unit 001', '2019-01-01', N'Allen Smithee');

select  stuff((
    select  N', ' + file_as_name
    from    @lease_contacts
    where   [name] = N'Cedar Villas'
    and unit = N'Unit 001'
    and lease_start_date = '2019-01-01'
    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, N'')
```

Which gives you:

```
(No column name)
------------------------------------
John Doe, Jane Smith, Allen Smithee
```

NOTE: Most references use `STUFF(..., 1, 1, '')` when dealing with plain comma separators i.e.: `','`. Because you're wanting to use `', '` with a space you need to adjust this to `STUFF(..., 1, 2, '')`.

Comment: Thanks Shawn!  And yes, I will delete the other duplicate.